# Reference request on basic properties of the principal symbols of pseudodifferential operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

I am looking for a reference which would treat some very elementary properties of the principal symbols of pseudodifferential operators, such as conjugation and products. In particular, I am interested in seeing an exact proof which shows e.g. that either the principal symbol $\sigma_{A^*}$ of a conjugate of a pseudodifferential operator $A$ is equal to the conjugate of the principal symbol of $A$, $\sigma_A$ or that there $\sigma_{A^*A} = \sigma_{AA^*} = \left|\sigma_A\right|^2$. Googling has not helped me because I am so new to microlocal analysis/PsiOps that I don't know how to ask the right questions. As of writing, I couldn't find any source which proved/disproved these two properties.

Edit: I also do not know how to prove these claims.

Comment: Did you try to prove them? ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I have not tried because I don't know how to play around with the pseudodifferential operators. To be specific, as of writing I do not know how to connect the quantization formula often used for pseudodifferential operators to the symbolic sum finite sum of differential operators with certain coefficients.

Comment: You don’t need the quantization formula. Look for a book that introduces the basics. Michael Taylor and Francois Treves wrote some. There are the old notes by Louis Nirenberg.